# What URL should I use to connect to an SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I have TurtoiseSVN and ankhSVN installed.  I created a repository on my computer: `C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Subversion\Repository\`.

I am trying to connect to this repository from my co-worker's computer. What should this URL be?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will need to run the svnserve daemon on your computer, or run an apache server with the necessary modules, to allow your colleague to access this locally stored repository. For a simple case like this I would recommend svnserve, it should be simpler to configure and run.

The url would then be:

```
svn://<your_ip>/<repository_name>
```

As opposed to an http or file protocol URL for apache and local filesystem based repositories.

Read this page for details on how to set up svnserve it on Windows:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html

Comment: I ended up installing svnserve as a windows service.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

```
file:///\\COMPUTERNAME\SharedFolderName\
```

I probably don't have the slashes right, but it's something crazy like that.

Oh, and he'll have to create a folder share. That would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I really think my file-system solution is simpler than setting up a whole Apache server, but whatever.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, anyway. Except that it should be "you'll have to create a folder share", not "he".

Comment: Ah, yes. I got that part backward.

Comment: It was the solution for me: the three slashes were required to use the repository with the file protocol (from intellij using the tortoise subversion client): `file:///C:/mydir/myrepository`

Answer (score 1):

Try svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Repository/

The default port is 3690 if you have a firewall to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head...

svn://YOURCOMPUTERNAME/repository/project/trunk

or

svn://xxx.yyy.zzz.www/repository/project/trunk

Don't forget to open the firewall if you are running on WindowsXP.

Comment: This will not work, unless (s)he sets up a SVN server.