# After setting up the svnserve Server, what URL will the client use to access the server?

Tags: repository, svn

**Client** ---| Internet |--- **Server**

So I have set-up an svnserver server and it is running already. I typed svsnserve.exe --daemon --root "C:\Documents and Settings\Subversion Directory" on cmd. I have also set-up a repository and I can browse it through TortoiseSVN. I am the server computer. What I want to do now is for a client computer to access the server. Only TortoiseSVN is installed to the client, no SVN server. What I want to do now is checkout the repository from the server, what do I write in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely:

```
svn://<hostname>/<repository_name>
```

See [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174773/svn-url-format) question (very similar)

Comment: what goes into the hostname? my ip address? my computer name? i've tried both but it doesn't work.

Comment: The host that you're trying to connect to. You should do some network diagnostics and try to ping/telnet on the SVN port etc. to determine what's working

Answer (score 1):

For internet based repositories, you would be better off hosting via a web-server. [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is free, and provides an easy way of hosting SVN on windows using Apache (which it installs and configures). It tells you the SVN http path in the management tool - of course, you'll need to ensure you have line-of-sight/DNS between the devices, which might mean some more configuration / firewall rules / port forwarding / etc.

Answer (score 1):

Start daemon:

```
svnserve -d -r my_repo
```

Connect using RapidSVN:
(Bookmarks > Add Existing Repository...)
*No need to specify "my_repo" here*

```
svn://localhost
```