# Accessing SVN repository when the server is run in daemon mode

Tags: svn, repository

Am running the SVN server in daemon mode using `svnserve -d`. How can I frame the URL for accessing my repository in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `svn://[server-host-name]/[path]`

More info in this question: [SVN URL Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174773/svn-url-format)